# memset is placing -1 into my array instead of the value I specified, what is going on?

Tags: c++, memset

```
    int * best = new int[numNodes];
memset(best,numeric_limits<int>::max()/2,numNodes*sizeof(int));
    int test = numeric_limits<int>::max()/2;
```

printing out the array gives me an array of all -1.
printing out the int 'test' gives me the correct value of '1073741823'

I am including 'cstring' for the use of memset. 
Here is the doc I am following:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/

Why am I getting this result? I am sure it might be something obvious, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memset fills the memory with an unsigned char:

```
void *memset(void *DST, int C, size_t LENGTH);
   This  function converts the argument C into an unsigned char and fills the
   first LENGTH characters of the array pointed to by DST to the value.
```